# Oddity with button placement

Tags: vb6

I'm having an oddity with Visual Basic 6. In a number of activities, I use the following code to position a save commandbutton at the bottom right of the activity:

```
ButtonTop = UserControl.Height - cmdSave.Height - 90
ButtonLeft = cmdSave.Width + 90
Call cmdSave.Move(UserControl.Width - ButtonLeft, ButtonTop)
```

This works perfectly except in one activity, where only the top half of the button is visible; the rest extends off the bottom of the screen. Any ideas on what could cause that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be worth checking that the bottom/height of the user control on the form is where you expect it to be, if that drops below the bottom of the form then that could throw it out.

If that doesn't cure it have a look at the scale mode for the form, and the control and see if it's the same as the other controls/forms.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was it - the scale mode was set to user instead of twips. Thank you so much.